# MVC 3 with unobstrusive parse doesn't work on JQuery Dialog?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've a MVC 3 application with Input tag with "data-val-remote" tags. 
e.g.

```
 <div id="dialog" title="Test">  
       <input class="captcha_input" data-val="true" 
       data-val-remote="ErrorMessage" 
       data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.value" 
       data-val-remote-url="/Controller/Action" 
       data-val-required="Required" id="TestID" name="TestValue" type="text" value="">
   </div>
```

Snippet of JQUERY that shows the Dialog:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
            height: 260,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false
        });
```

Unfortunately, the MVC remote validation works by itself but when shown on JQuery Dialog the "data-val-remote" tags stops to work.

I would have thought that even if we display the INPUT fields on Dialog it still inherits all the Javascript includes and form actions?

Could someone help whether this is a bug or is there any workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The MVC unobtrusive validators subscribes on the input control's events once when the DOM is ready. If you have dynamic content on your page you need to instruct the validation framework to redo the subscription.

In you case the dynamic content is the dailog. Because it will create a new div with the old content, so you need to reapply the validators after the dialog creation/open with:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#dialog");
```

Comment: I tried putting above line like this but did not work $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#dialog');